# Multilevel parsing using shell command

Tags: string, shell, parsing, terminal

I have a file in the following format

```
/////
name 1
start_occurrence:
occurrence 1
occurrence 2

///
name 2
start_occurance:
occurrence 1
occurrence 2

///
name 3
start_occurrence:
occurrence 1
occurrence 2
occurrence 3
```

All I need is to make a count of the number of occurrences for each name and save them in a CSV file. Can I do it using any combination of shell commands? Yes I can do it programmatically, but looking for a bunch of shell commands in a pipe lined fashion.

"`names`" can be anything. Names does not come with a pattern. Only catch is that the line after `///` is the name. Also `Occurrence` does not have any number with it, anyline that starts with `occurrence` or have `occurrence` is a subject of interest.

Comment: Edit my answer, now I use regex to match the occurrence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk 'c=="THISISNAME"{b=$0;c="";}$1=="///"{c="THISISNAME"}$0~/\<occurrence\>/{a[b]+=1;}END{for (i in a){print i" "a[i]}}'  YOUR_FILE_HERE
```

explain:

```
if match the name start condition ($1=="///"), mark the c to THISISNAME.

if this is the name line (c=="THISISNAME"), mark the name line with b, and mark c as name part ended(c="").

if match the occurrence condition ($0~/\<occurrence\>/), make a[b] += 1.

use a map a to remark the occurrence time of each name.
```

awk use EREs, the $0~/EREs/ means $0 match the regex. the '\<' and '>' means '\b' in PREs

Comment: HI can you please a little bit elaborate it? The "name"  does not have to have numbers after it, it can be anything like abcd, xyz10, etc.

Comment: @Pbasak  update the answer, and remember I mark the name start with explicit three splash here. If your condition is more than three splash, you should replace $1=="///" with regex.

Comment: Hi you solution works for name 2 and name 3, but for the first name it does not print the name, only the count. I do not know how to put line breaks in comments here but I have placed , in line breaks. so here is the output: 

2,
name 2 2,
name 3 3,

Comment: Sorry I got it. The number of slashes. Now it works. Thank you.

Comment: one thing missing, occurnece can be anywhere in the line. In that case what can be done? Like say 

"A sudden occurrence happened"

Comment: Thank you. Now it works. Although i needed to remove \< and \> part, and apply (.)*occurence. I did not know of ERE and BRE before.